# The yield request is not working for sub function

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Started with python and scraping a week ago, so please go easy people. So the 
`def parse()` has a request which calls `parseCa1L1()` and `parseCatL1()` has a request which calls `detailCollector()`. The yield request in the `parseCatL1()` is not taking it to `detailCollector()`.

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.log('url entered is :' + response.url)
    item = BasicItem()
    for mainCat in response.css('ul.mm-listview > li'):
        item['title'] = mainCat.css('a > span.meditle1::text').extract_first()
        item['url'] = mainCat.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        item['url6'] = item['url']
        request = scrapy.Request(item['url'], callback=self.parseCatL1)
        request.meta['item'] = item['url6']
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request  

def parseCatL1(self, response):
    self.log('l1 url entered is :' + response.url)
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['listing'] = response.css('ul.mm-listview > li')
    if item['listing'] == []:
        print 'l1 if entered'
        item['url6'] = item['url']
        request = scrapy.Request(item['url6'], callback=self.detailCollector)
        request.meta['item'] = item['url6']
        print request
        yield request

def detailCollector(self, response):
     print 'detail collector entered'
```

and print request in `parseCatL1()` prints `<GET https://www.some.com>`
and if it is yielding request then why is it not printing `detail collector entered`

Below is the logs:

> DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/AC-Compressor-Dealers/nct-10002128> (referer: https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/311/11060105_3/AC-Compressor-Dealers_b2c)
>
> DEBUG: l1 url entered is :https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/AC-Compressor-Dealers/nct-10002128
>   l1 if entered
>   https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/AC-Compressor-Dealers-Tecumseh/nct-10002136
>   https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/AC-Compressor-Dealers-Tecumseh/nct-10002136>
>
> DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/AC-Compressor-Dealers-Tecumseh/nct-10002136> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
>
> DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/AC-Compressor-Dealers-Daikin/nct-10002130> (referer: https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/311/11060105_3/AC-Compressor-Dealers_b2c)
>
> DEBUG: l1 url entered is :https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/AC-Compressor-Dealers-Daikin/nct-10002130
>   l1 if entered

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: Sure thing, please hold on.

Comment: yield doesn't mean it will be parsed. Scrapy may have problem to read this page, it can skip duplicate url, it can skip urls which are not in "allowed_domains". You should have  messages/logs on screen with more info.

Comment: you might just have to do return in your `parseCatL1()` function.  `parseCatL1()` has become a generator once you use yield keyword and what you implemented is not a proper way to utilising the generators.

Comment: @PrakashPalnati `yield` is correct and expected in `scrapy` - all parsers can work as generators.

Comment: @PrakashPalnati i have tried return request. It is not working either.

Comment: print urls before you use them in `Request` to see if they are correct - maybe they don't have domain name and you have to use `response.urljoin()`

Comment: DEBUG: l1 url entered is :https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/AC-Compressor-Dealers/nct-10002128
l1 if entered
<GET https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/AC-Compressor-Dealers-Tecumseh/nct-10002136>
DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/AC-Compressor-Dealers-Tecumseh/nct-10002136> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/AC-Compressor-Dealers-Danfoss/nct-10002131> (referer: https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/311/11060105_3/AC-Compressor-Dealers_b2c)

Comment: above comment is whats happening when i crawl. and the same loop repeats. But does not enter the detailController().

Comment: @furas the urls are correct. Just recheced with print.

Comment: put logs in question. it will be more readable.

Comment: see log - there is `"Filtered duplicated request"` - as for me you try to use `detailedCollector` with url which you already read before (with request for `parswCatL1`) so scrapy skips this request.

Comment: @furas Thanks, i get it now. So is there anyway to avoid ignoring the duplicates, or any better way to improve the code.

Comment: most natural: get details in `parseCatL1`. if you want to have it in separated function then execute it in `parseCatL1` as normal function.

Comment: @furas Thanks a lot dude. I'll keep that in mind next time:)